# How to pass table name dynamically in stored procedure - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I wanted to create a stored procedure in such a way that it accepts table name as parameter and pass it dynamically in the procedure. For example: I want to pass table name 'DATA.WORK_CPG' as paramter to Stored proc.

**Here is the actual procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Proc_Sample
(
ApplicationID IN varchar2,
CType IN varchar2,
WBName IN varchar2,
WBList OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)AS 
BEGIN
OPEN WBList 
FOR

  SELECT 
    WO.RECORDNUMBER  AS RECORDNUMBER,
  FROM DATA.ASSIGN_WB WB 
  INNER JOIN DATA.WORK_CPG WO ON WO.PZINSKEY = WB.PXREFOBJECTKEY 
  INNER JOIN COMMON.REF_APPLICATION RA ON RA.APPLICATIONNAME = WB.PXAPPLICATION 
  WHERE RA.APPLICATIONID = ApplicationID AND WB.ASSIGNEDID IN ( select regexp_substr(WBName,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(WBName, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );

END Proc_Sample;
```

**And I tried to convert it as below by passing table name as parameter to Stored procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  Proc_Sample                  
(
TableName in varchar2,
ApplicationID IN varchar2,
CaseType IN varchar2,
WBName IN varchar2,
WBList OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)AS 
stmt varchar2(10000);
BEGIN
--OPEN WBList 
--FOR
stmt := ' SELECT 
 WO.RECORDNUMBER  AS RECORDNUMBER,
FROM DATA.PC_ASSIGN_WB WB 
INNER JOIN  ' ||  TableName || ' WO ON WO.PZINSKEY = WB.PXREFOBJECTKEY 
INNER JOIN COMMON.REF_APPLICATION RA ON RA.APPLICATIONNAME = WB.PXAPPLICATION 
WHERE RA.APPLICATIONID = ApplicationID AND WB.ASSIGNEDID IN (select regexp_substr(''' || WBName || ''',''[^,]+'', 1, level) from dual 
            connect by regexp_substr(''' || WBName || ''', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null)';

--execute immediate stmt;
open WBList for stmt; 
END Proc_Sample;
```

**Is this correct way of doing?** 
Note - Procedure compiled successfully.
**Error:**
While executing this from client application, I am getting the following error
**ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name**

Comment: oracle != sql-server != mysql

Comment: I've removed all the conflicting tags. Please tag properly.

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . Yes, but you only get Oracle errors with Oracle.

Comment: you probably have too many quotes or some other syntax error.  print out the string and execute it manually and see what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer using bind variables :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_Sample(ApplicationID varchar2,
                                           --CType         varchar2,
                                             WBName        varchar2,
                                             RecNum        OUT DATA.WORK_CPG.RECORDNUMBER%type ) AS 
  WBList  sys_refcursor;          
  stmt    varchar2(10000);                            
BEGIN
  stmt := 'SELECT WO.RECORDNUMBER AS RECORDNUMBER
              FROM DATA.ASSIGN_WB WB
             INNER JOIN DATA.WORK_CPG WO
                ON WO.PZINSKEY = WB.PXREFOBJECTKEY
             INNER JOIN COMMON.REF_APPLICATION RA
                ON RA.APPLICATIONNAME = WB.PXAPPLICATION
             WHERE RA.APPLICATIONID = :AppID
               AND WB.ASSIGNEDID IN
                   (SELECT regexp_substr(:WBN, ''[^,]+'', 1, level)
                      FROM dual
                   CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:WBN, ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null)';
   OPEN WBList FOR stmt USING ApplicationID, WBName, WBName;
   FETCH WBList INTO RecNum;
   CLOSE WBList; 

END Proc_Sample;
/
```

The first returned value for the query will be out for RecNum whenever called :

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SQL> Declare
  rcn DATA.WORK_CPG.RECORDNUMBER%type;
Begin
  Proc_Sample(118,'abc',rcn);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line(rcn);
End;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=85674d4e5fc200d178198d39e63eda5f)</kbd>

If your aim is just to print out all the returning records, then 
replace

`FETCH WBList INTO RecNum;`

with

```
LOOP
     FETCH WBList INTO RecNum;  
  EXIT WHEN WBList%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(WBList.RECORDNUMBER);   
END LOOP;
```

within the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. A quick question, how does these bind variables :AppID and :WBN gets derived. Those are not being set anywhere in query right.

Comment: Excuse me @daks , WBName should be repeated, since they're set through `OPEN WBList FOR stmt USING ApplicationID, WBName, WBName` with the number and appearence order of bind variables(`:AppID,:WBN,:WBN`) in the string. I've fixed.